# How can i add an optional list parameter to my keyword at robotframework?

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to add optional dictionary and list to my keyword, how can assign their default values?

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried and what the error is that you're seeing?

Comment: Are you writing this keyword in robot, in python, or some other language? It would help if you could provide a [mcve] that shows us what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

In the [RF User Guide](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#default-values-with-user-keywords) you can find examples of how you can add arguments with default values. In short, after the variable you have to add "=" and the value by default. Here is an example:

```
One Required And One With Default
[Arguments]    ${required}    ${optional}=default
[Documentation]    This keyword takes 1-2 arguments
Log    Required: ${required}
Log    Optional: ${optional}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer covers correctly keyword parameters with defeat values, your question is for a default *list* one.

And this is not allowed by Robot Framework syntax *(and in python, having a default value being a predefined list is a source of a lot of pain and hidden bugs :)*. So the solution for that is to have a parameter which default value is `None` *(usually, really anything the caller would not pass would do)*, and check was it set in the call; if not - assign it to the default list, inside the keyword:

```
My Keyword That Accepts Optional List
    [Arguments]    ${the_list}=${None}

    ${the default value}=    Create List   member0    the other one
    ${the_list}=    Set Variable If    $the_list is None    ${the default value}    # no argument passed when the keyword was called
                            ...        ${the_list}    # an argument was passed, leave the variable as it was
```